# Match checkbox data with page title to show certain items

Tags: php, custom-field

I want to show the projects that has had it's checkbox ticked as Branding, if it's on the Branding page (i.e the page title is Branding).

To explain the code a bit:

This line show's all the checkboxes that have been ticked for each project so it will output "Branding", "Web", "Print" if they have been ticked.

```
implode(', ',get_field('categories')
```

This next line is just checking the page title is "Branding":

```
implode(', ',get_field('categories')
```

I'm trying to put these both in an if statement where it would just output the checked boxes and if they match the title then output them.

```
<?php if(implode(', ',get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Branding"); {
echo "testing"; 
}
?>
```

The code above shows what I want to do but it doesn't quite work.

**IMPORTANT: I'm using [this plugin](http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/) to create the custom checkboxes so please bear that in mind.**

Comment: @Rob: This looks like it can be handled with a hierarchial custom taxonomy. You get almost everything "for free" that way. Is there a reason you are not using that? (Use `@Jan` when you reply in a comment and I get a notification)

Comment: @Jan I'm not really sure what that is to be honest!! I just used the custom field plugin to create all my custom data for each project. I'm completely open to anything that'll do the job.

Comment: @Rob: Can you [come to the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/stoppress) so we can explain it there? It's really simple, but I can't just explain it in comments.

Comment: Why do you want to match the title? Do you have dynamic titles or do you just want to output meta box conditionals based on custom pages/tags/categories. Your question seems odd.

Comment: I have no idea, I just want to show the projects that branding has been ticked in it's checkbox to show on the branding page. No one seems to be reading the part where it says I'm using a plugin to create the custom fields i.e the checkboxes.

Comment: @Jan I've simplified the question a bit to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out myself reading around, solved it with this:

```
   <div id="grid">
<?php $args = array(
    'depth'        => 0,
    'child_of'     => 411 );
$pages = get_pages(array('child_of'));
$grid_title = $post->post_title;

foreach($pages as $post)
{
setup_postdata($post);
$fields = get_fields();?>

<?php if($fields->company_name != "") : ?>
<!-- Any new tags will need to be added below -->
<?php if((in_array("Branding", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Branding") || (in_array("Creative", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Creative") || (in_array("Development", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Development") || (in_array("Exhibition", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Exhibition") || (in_array("Packaging", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Packaging") || (in_array("Print", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Print") || (in_array("SEO", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "SEO") || (in_array("Usability", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Usability") || (in_array("Web", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Web") || (in_array("Campaign", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Campaign") || (in_array("Copywriting", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Copywriting") || (in_array("Feasibility", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Feasibility") || (in_array("Research", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Research") || (in_array("Social Media", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Social Media")){
     echo "
        <div class=\"grid-box\" onclick=\"location.href='" . get_page_link($post->ID) ."';\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">
        <div class=\"phase-1\">
           <img class=\"grid-image\" src=\"" . $fields->thumb_image . "\" alt=\"" . $fields->company_name ."\" height=\"152\" width=\"210\" />
           <div class=\"grid-heading\">
                <h2>". $fields->company_name ."</h2>
                <h3>" . implode(', ',get_field('categories')) ."</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=\"phase-2\">
            <div class=\"grid-info\">
                <h4>". $fields->project_name ."</h4>
                <p>". $fields->description ."</p>
            </div>
            <div class=\"grid-heading-hover\">
                <h2>". $fields->company_name ."</h2>
                <h3>". implode(', ',get_field('categories')) ."</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
     ";
}
else {
    echo "  <div class=\"grid-box\" onclick=\"location.href='" . get_page_link($post->ID) ."';\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">
        <div class=\"phase-1\">
           <img class=\"grid-image\" src=\"" . $fields->thumb_image . "\" alt=\"" . $fields->company_name ."\" height=\"152\" width=\"210\" />
           <div class=\"grid-heading\">
                <h2>". $fields->company_name ."</h2>
                <h3>" . implode(', ',get_field('categories')) ."</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=\"phase-2\">
            <div class=\"grid-info\">
                <h4>". $fields->project_name ."</h4>
                <p>". $fields->description ."</p>
            </div>
            <div class=\"grid-heading-hover\">
                <h2>". $fields->company_name ."</h2>
                <h3>". implode(', ',get_field('categories')) ."</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>";
}

else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>    

<?php
}

wp_reset_query();
?>        
</div>
```