# Convert imploded plain text into links

Tags: php

I'm completely open on how to do this:

I have the line:

```
echo implode(', ',get_field('categories'));
```

Which is outputting this:

```
Branding, Web, Print
```

I have 20 or so options it can output depending on what checkboxes were ticked.

At the moment, what it's outputting is just plain text. How can I make each tag a link? The link would need to be unique per tag so:

```
<a href="tags/design/branding">Branding</a>, <a href="tags/design/web">Web</a>, <a href="tags/marketing/print">print</a>
```

UPDATE:
The first part of the question is working thanks to Brady. I now have an additional question -

Using Brady's answer on the line:

```
$elements[] = '<a href="/tags/design/' . strtolower($category) . '" title="' . $category . '">' . $category .'</a>';
```

If you look at the href it has the link /tags/design/, some of the tags it's outputting are using the correct link but some are from another section and the link should be /tags/marketing/. How can I account for this? (Not that I know how to do this, someone will need to show me!) Could I create an array with the tags "Branding, Web, Print" and if the $category variable matches this then give it the variable $design. Could I then create another array with "Advertising, Analysis, Campaign" and give it the variable $marketing if the $category matches that. Then in the link I could put href="/tags/$design/$category" or href="/tags/$marketing/$category"?

So a couple of examples would be (I'll put them as normal links):

From the design section:

```
<a href="/tags/design/branding">Branding</a>
<a href="/tags/design/web">Web</a>
<a href="/tags/design/print">Print</a>
```

From the marketing section:

```
<a href="/tags/marketing/advertising">Advertising</a>
<a href="/tags/marketing/analysis">Analysis</a>
<a href="/tags/marketing/campaign">Campaign</a>
```

There are only two sections design and marketing, within those sections there are several tags, if that makes sense. The sections in WP are setup like this:

tags > design > (each tag - branding, web, print is it's own page).
tags > marketing > (each tag - advertising, analysis, campaign is it's own page).

Comment: can you give us a few examples of what get_field() will return? Maybe do a `print_r()` on it. As far as I know get_field() is not a built in function.

Comment: I don't mind if I have to write out all the tags and do some kind of if statement to check if it's within the design or marketing section. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: I think you've miss understood me. Where does `get_field()` come from? are you using a plugin or theme that creates this function? Because its not native WP then its hard to solve this issue without know what this function is doing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using this http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/ to create custom fields. The 'get_field()' is needed to grab the checkbox info from WP.

Comment: I guess it's kinda related to my other question - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/17560/5415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$categories = get_field('categories');
$elements = array();
foreach($categories as $category) {
    //do something
    $elements[] = '<a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $name .'</a>';
}
echo implode(',', $elements);
?>
```

at the `//do something` here you should find what the URL should be for your category/tag

something like [get_tag_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tag_link) might be of use.

Also have you looked at using [the_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) It does what your after and can be used in the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I've adjusted the link line to this $elements[] = '<a href="/tags/design/' . $category . '" title="' . $category . '">' . $category .'</a>';

Comment: Is it possible to make the $category in the href lowercase? As it is just puts it in as uppercase causing a 404 not found.

Comment: use php function `strtolower()`

Comment: Yay thanks, I've just noticed something, I'll update my question.

Comment: @Rob - the last link in your example has a different structure - it is linking to /tags/marketing/ instead of /tags/design/ - is this the case with some of the tags? in which case, you may need to use something like http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by to get the link.

Comment: Yep (I've updated my question with more info), there are only two sections - design and marketing, they then have several tags within each one.

Comment: @Michael is it possible to show a code example please?

Comment: @Rob - sorry, i withdraw the suggestion: i come to realize that it will not work because it will output 'normal' permalinks, and not relative links; and the link structure is very likely not to reflect your example.